# Hiding items from the 'tasks' popup in visual studio designer

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, controls, windows-forms-designer

I have a custom TreeView for which I'd like to hide the ImageList dropdown from the designer tasks popup. Is there any (relatively simple) way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[Designer(@"System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner, System.Design," +
            " Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]
class MyTreeView : TreeView
{
}
```

This will revert to the default Control Designer Verb list which only contains "Dock in Parent Container".

To add "Edit Nodes..." you'll need to look into creating your own ControlDesigner-derived class which adds it.  Easiest might be using Reflector and copying the TreeViewDesigner functionalities and remove ImageList.

Comment: Any idea why I can't find TreeViewDesigner in Reflector? (Or ControlDesigner for that matter?) They gotta be in there somewhere, but I can't seem to find them... (grrrrr)....

Comment: Microsoft separated them from main code.  They are in a separate DLL 'system.Design.dll"

Comment: Ahhh! There it is. Thanks dude.